# Style post formats differently only in single

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to use post types to style video posts differently. This should be quite easily achieved with custom post types.

But I only want the video post type to affect the post when it is in "single".

In other words I want the front page to stay as it is but when a video post is clicked on (and single.php is rendered) I want it to be styled differently than regular posts.

How can I achieve this?

I have read a dozen articles about custom post types, but all of them explain how to render CPT on the front page, which is not what I need.

Functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
    'aside',
    'gallery',
    'image',
    'link',
    'video',
    'quote',
    'link',
    'video',
    'status', 
    'audio', 
    'chat'
) );
```

I am using _s for theme development so inside the theme root folder I have a folder called template-parts with 
content-none.php
content-page.php
content-search.php
content-single.php
content.php
and
**single-video.php**

Comment: Woah - do you actually mean custom post type, or are you referring to a post with the format "video"?

Comment: Sorry, I was indeed referring to the "standard" post format. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I think I fixed it by renaming single.video.php to content-single-video.php. This is because of the hierarchy of files that _s generates.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta be careful with your terminology - custom post types are something completely different!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `single-{post-type}.php` template, as described in [the Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: I have read the whole article and dozen others. It does not explain how to do this practically. The documentation merely states that it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `single-{name-of-your-custom-post-type}.php` in your theme folder?

Comment: I have but nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

single.php file or custom single-{post_type}.php

```
<?php 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
```

make a new template file **content-video.php** customize  video format post.

When you add post format to custom post type add support in your function.php
add_post_type_support( 'post_type_name', 'post-formats' );